# Nested one-to-many relationship Laravel filtering to one record

Tags: sql, laravel, one-to-many, with-statement, eager

I have a product model, inventory model, and user_inventory model and the user_inventory model has sale_price. I want to receive the product inventory which has smallest user inventory sale price and also the user_inventory

the output show be like:

```
products:{
       id
       inventories:{
           id
           product_id
            user_inventories:{
                 id
                 inventory_id
                 sale_price:smallest value
                  }
        }
},.....
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could print all the tables schema (just columns) here as an example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it may help to define a new model relation in inventory model like this:

```
    public function lowestPrice()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('user_inventory','inventory_id')->orderBy('sale_price');
    }
```

so it may return lowest sale_price of user_inventory  for each inventory

for example:

```
$product = product::with('inventory.lowestPrice')->first();
```

Comment: I want to receive the all products inventory which has the smallest user inventory sale price and also the user_inventory